# How to use Xephyr in Ubuntu OS customisation?

Tags: chroot

I customise ubuntu OS often and prefer cli method and build from scratch. I am currently getting it done in a hack method with some GUI. I know Xephyr is a display server and I 've used it once in customisation and lately I forgot how to use it. Now I want to know how to use Xephyr to see my customised chroot environment. I know its required to set correct display settings and I barely remember it how I get it done with my chroot Customisation Folder. Anybody , kindly help me out.

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=620003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start Xephyr

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x1024 -br -reset -terminate 2> /dev/null :2 &
```

ssh into the chroot/server

```
ssh -XfC -c blowfish user@server xfce4-session
```

Substitute your window manager for "xfce4-session"

For details see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=620003

Comment: Well  yea  thats it. I am nearing to the end.  I don't what to ssh to other server rather Could you tell me how I can view the desktop of my customising OS , where I have extracted ISO and  unsquashed filesystem  to a folder and opening terminal there and chroot to install softwares and customise.

Comment: ssh is really the easiest method as you can not chroot without using root